# How to wait on multiple signals

Tags: vhdl

I need to sync the computation of two signals, which are generated in two processes.

```
architecture sm1 of SubModule is
  signal s1, s2 : float (5 downto -11);
begin

  PROCESS_1 : process (N, j, CLK)
    ...
  begin
    ...
    s1 <= ...
  end process;

  PROCESS_2 : process (N, j, CLK)
    ...
  begin
    ...
    s2 <= ...
  end process;

  PROCESS_SUM : process
  begin
    wait on s1 and s2;  -- something like this 
    result <= s1 + s2;
  end process;
end sm1;
```

The code demonstrates the idea, processes `PROCESS_1` and `PROCESS_2` perform separate tasks, but the sum of their results is the result of the entity's computation. The general case is to expect that `PROCESS_1` and `PROCESS_2` will take a different amount of clock cycles to compute their results. How do I make sure that no old value of `s1` or `s2` is used in the third process?

If I'm having a wrong approach or misconceptions here, feel free to suggest other ideas or clarify my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable latency calculations, it is sometimes useful to add a signal that
indicates ready result for the calculation, thus a `s1_rdy` and `s2_rdy`, where
these ready indications are `'1'` iff the result is ready.

With the added ready signals, the code may have structure like:

```
architecture sm1 of SubModule is
  signal s1, s2 : float (5 downto -11);
  signal s1_rdy, s2_rdy, result_rdy : std_logic;
begin

  PROCESS_1 : process (N, j, CLK)
    ...
  begin
    ...
    s1 <= ...
    s1_rdy <= '1';  -- Assigned to '0' when not ready
  end process;

  PROCESS_2 : process (N, j, CLK)
    ...
  begin
    ...
    s2 <= ...
    s2_rdy <= '1';  -- Assigned to '0' when not ready
  end process;

  -- Combine s1 and s2 with combined ready indication
  result <= s1 + s2;
  result_rdy <= s1_rdy and s2_rdy;

end sm1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see how that could help me in my situation. I will try it out. However, I'm also interested in the general case: is there a way to implement multiple wait instructions. A workaround can potentially always be found, but I find it hard to believe that the standard does not predict something like it.

Comment: It depends on the application.  For synthesizable code, the design is typically synchronous, where wait is only used to infer flip-flops, which puts specific limitations on how wait is used.  The suggestion with ready signals is based on this.  For non-synthesizable code there are multiple ways of using wait, but this is only relevant for test bench code.

Answer (score 0):

Morten's answer is good, and demonstrates a real-world solution.

In terms of your actual question, *how to wait for both things to be ready*, the code which most "looks like" your suggestion would be:

```
PROCESS_SUM : process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then 
        if s1 = '1' and s2 = '1' then
           result <= s1 + s2;
        end if;
    end if;
  end process;
```

but you still need to pass on a "valid" flag with the sum, as Morten does, and you've added an extra level of logic in front of your adder which is unnecessary